# How to do string padding in ballerina lang

Tags: ballerina

I have an integer value and I want to pad with leading "0" to this integer value. How can I do that in ballerina?

```
int i = 1;
```

Expected output should be

```
0000000001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any ready made Ballerina padding functions or number formaters, (e.g. there's nothing related in [stringutils](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/api-docs/ballerina/stringutils/index.html)) so one should likely to write one. E.g:

```
import ballerina/io;

function lpad(int size, string value, string padStr) returns string {
    int diff = size - value.length();
    if (diff < 1) {
        return value;
    }

    string padding = "";
    while (diff > 0) {
        padding += padStr;
        diff -= 1;
    }

    return padding + value;
}

public function main() {
    int i = 1;
    io:println(lpad(10, i.toString(), "0"));
}
```

Comment: I managed to do myself something like you shared, I was expecting there may be some build in function to do that

Comment: This is not the correct answer, please see the `io:sprintf` answer instead. However at the moment of the writing (Ballerina 1.1)  the [io:sprintf](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/api-docs/ballerina/io/functions.html#sprintf) format string parameter is not documented.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `io:sprintf()` function for this. Taking the same example you have given,

```
int i = 1;
io:println(io:sprintf("%09d", i));
```

The above will print`000000001`.

Comment: Where the format string is documented ? Obviously not in the obvious place [io:sprintf](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/api-docs/ballerina/io/functions.html#sprintf) ?

Comment: This isn't documented in the docs unfortunately, and yes, the documentation for `sprintf()` needs considerable improvement. There's an issue reported for this: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/12710

Comment: Aparently io:sprintf function was removed, String template literals should be used instead (https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-standard-library/issues/1031).
Examples of usage at https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-standard-library/issues/982#issuecomment-783184096